# Reduction Rule Approach Used in Factoring a Quartic

Tags: polynomials, factoring, quartics

Can someone point me to an article or textbook where I can learn more about the reduction technique used in the third answer titled **Rational Root Theorem Solution** to the question asked in [Factorization of quartic polynomial.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2082195/factorization-of-quartic-polynomial)?  The key point that interests me in that answer was how the potential quartic factor $x^2-px-q$ is written as $x^2 = p x + q$ and how this last expression is used as a reduction rule.

I am asking if anyone knows if the reduction approach used in this particular answer is developed or discussed in detail in some article or textbook?

Thank you.