# Solve for x (with proper steps)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$(x^2+x+1)^2=x^2(3x^2+x+1)$$

In addition to using ai solvers are able to give me the final solution for this equation. But I am not able to get the **exact steps or procedure** to reach the solution. I need a clear step by step procedure to attain the solution. So I seek this community with esteemed mathematicians to solve my problem

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please update your question text to show what you tried (in addition to using "ai solvers"), and especially anything you had difficulty with, to determine a final solution yourself. Thanks.

Comment: Where does this problem come from? Please see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: @TobyMak bro the problem is I don't know how did the answer come so you please help if you can by solve the question step by step please post it

Comment: Sorry, but most people on this site won't answer unless you have sufficient context. You are welcome to post this question on another site.

Comment: I don't need most of the people to answer. I only need the person who are ready help the beginners. Every one cannot be a pro in the beginning

Comment: @TobyMak Do I count as an exception?

Comment: I am only judging on the quality of your answer, since it does not give too much to the OP. When this question is closed and possibly deleted, you will lose the upvote anyway.

Comment: @Ryka Yes, I understand. In fact Math SE is for all levels of maths, as written in the [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour). However, your question is not a good question by our site's standards, so you can either improve it, or ask elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

We can rewrite the equation as
$$2x^4-x^3-2x^2-2x-1=0$$
which can be factored into two quadratics (by [any of several hand methods](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2082195/357390)):
$$(x^2-x-1)(2x^2+x+1)=0$$
Solving these quadratics yields the roots $\frac{1\pm\sqrt5}2$ and $\frac{-1\pm\sqrt7i}4$.

Comment: Thanks for the link bro.

Answer (score 0):

It's $$(x^2+x+1)^2=x^2(x^2+x+1)+2x^4$$ or
$$(x^2+x+1)^2-x^2(x^2+x+1)-2x^4=0,$$ which gives
$$x^2+x+1=-x^2,$$ which is impossible for real $x$, or
$$x^2+x+1=2x^2.$$
Can you end it now?

The last step we cam make by the following way.

Let $x^2+x+1=a$.

Thus, we need to sove
$$a^2-x^2a-2x^4=0$$ or
$$a^2-2x^2a+x^2a-2x^4=0$$ or
$$a(a-2x^2)+x^2(a-2x^2)=0$$ or
$$(a+x^2)(a-2x^2)=0,$$ which gives
$$a=-x^2$$ or $$a=2x^2.$$

Comment: I am unable to understand please elaborate your answer

Comment: @Ryka I am ready. About which step do you say?

Comment: How does $$2x^2$$ appears in the last step

Comment: @Ryka Do you want that I'll solve this equation or you asked how I got this equation?

Comment: How did you arrive that equation

Comment: @Ryka I added something. See now.